# Why is MySQL's maximum time limit 838:59:59?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've run into the limit myself, but despite lots of chatter online, I've never seen an explanation for *why* the upper and lower limit for the TIME data type is what it is. The official reference at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html says

> TIME values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. The hours part may be so large because the TIME type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even negative).

But I'm wondering not why the hours part is allowed to be "so large", but why it's cut off where it is. There doesn't seem to be any significance to that many hours in regards to days, or if I try to imagine possible cutoffs for how many seconds could be stored as an integer. So why the range?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `TIME` values were always stored on 3 bytes in MySQL. But the format changed on [version 5.6.4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html). I suspect this was not the first time when it changed. But the other change, if there was one, happened long time ago and there is no public evidence of it. The MySQL source code history on GitHub starts with version 5.5 (the oldest commit is from May 2008) but the change I am looking for happened somewhere around 2001-2002 (MySQL 4 was launched in 2003)

The current format, as described in the documentation, uses 6 bits for seconds (possible values: `0` to `63`), 6 bits for minutes, 10 bits for hours (possible values: `0` to `1023`), 1 bit for sign (add the negative values of the already mentioned intervals) and 1 bit is unused and labelled "reserved for future extensions".

It is optimized for working with time components (hours, minutes, seconds) and doesn't waste much space. Using this format it's possible to store values between `-1023:59:59` and `+1023:59:59`. However MySQL limits the number of hours to `838`, probably for backward compatibility with applications that were written a while ago, when I think this was the limit.

Until version 5.6.4, the `TIME` values were also stored on 3 bytes and the components were packed as `days * 24 * 3600 + hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds`. This format was optimized for working with timestamps (because it was, in fact, a timestamp). Using this format it would be possible to store values in the range of about `-2330` to `+2330` hours. While having this big range of values available, MySQL was still limiting the values to `-838` to `+838` hours.

There was [bug #11655](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11655) on MySQL 4. It was possible to return `TIME` values outside the `-838..+838` range using nested `SELECT` statements. It was not a feature but a bug and it was fixed.

The only reason to limit the values to this range and to actively change any piece of code that produces `TIME` values outside it was backward compatibility.

I suspect MySQL 3 used a different format that, due to the way the data was packed, limited the valid values to the range `-838..+838` hours.

---

By looking into the current [MySQL's source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/include/my_time.h#L94) I found this interesting formula:

```
#define TIME_MAX_VALUE (TIME_MAX_HOUR*10000 + TIME_MAX_MINUTE*100 + TIME_MAX_SECOND)
```

Let's ignore for the moment the *`MAX`* part of the names used above and let's remember only that `TIME_MAX_MINUTE` and `TIME_MAX_SECOND` are numbers between `00` and `59`. The formula just concatenates the hours, minutes and seconds in a single integer number. For example, the value `170:29:45` becomes `1702945`.

This formula raises the following question: given that the `TIME` values are stored on 3 bytes with sign, what is the maximum positive value that can be represented this way?

The value we are looking for is `0x7FFFFF` that in decimal notation is `8388607`. Since the last four digits (`8607`) should be read as minutes (`86`) and seconds (`07`) and their maximum valid values is `59`, the greatest value that can be stored on 3 bytes with sign using the formula above is `8385959`. Which, as `TIME` is `+838:59:59`. Ta-da!

Guess what? The fragment of `C` code listed above was extracted from this:

```
/* Limits for the TIME data type */
#define TIME_MAX_HOUR 838
#define TIME_MAX_MINUTE 59
#define TIME_MAX_SECOND 59
#define TIME_MAX_VALUE (TIME_MAX_HOUR*10000 + TIME_MAX_MINUTE*100 + TIME_MAX_SECOND)
```

I am sure this is how MySQL 3 used to keep the `TIME` values internally. This format imposed the limitation of the range, and the backward compatibility requirement on the subsequent versions propagated the limitation to our days.

Comment: IS there any way to set this query time limit in Mysql 5.5 without recompiling from the source code

Answer (score 10):

`DATETIME` is stored based on a base of 10, see [Date and Time Data Type Representation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html):

> DATETIME: Eight bytes: A four-byte integer for date packed as YYYY×10000 + MM×100 + DD and a four-byte integer for time packed as HH×10000 + MM×100 + SS

For convinience and some other reasons, the (old) time format was encoded in the same way, using 3 bytes:

```
Hours * 10000 + Minutes * 100 + Seconds
```

This means:

```
3 bytes = 2^24 = 16.777.216
with sign: 2^23 = 8.388.608
```

Using the encoding, this represents the magical 838 hours. And max. 8608 seconds for the minutes and seconds (without overflow), which results in the largest valid time `838:59:59`. One nice thing about this is that the integer representation of that time, `8385959`, is easily readable to a human. But this encoding of course leaves gaps, invalid (unused) integer values (like `8309999`).

As of MySQL 5.6.4, `time` format changed its [encoding](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html) to

> ```
>   1 bit sign    (1= non-negative, 0= negative)
>   1 bit unused  (reserved for future extensions)
>  10 bits hour   (0-838)
>   6 bits minute (0-59) 
>   6 bits second (0-59) 
> ---------------------
>   24 bits = 3 bytes
> ```

Even though it could now store more hours, for compatibility it still just allows 838 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, it's hard to answer these types of questions without getting direct feedback from the designers of the database.

But there is some documentation regarding how the different data types are stored internally, and, to an extent, it can help us understand this a little bit.

For, instance, regarding the `TIME` data type, notice how it's stored internally according to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html):

> `TIME` encoding for nonfractional part:
>
> ```
>   1 bit sign    (1= non-negative, 0= negative)
>   1 bit unused  (reserved for future extensions)
>  10 bits hour   (0-838)
>   6 bits minute (0-59) 
>   6 bits second (0-59) 
> ---------------------
>   24 bits = 3 bytes
> ```

So, as you can see, the goal is to fit the information within 3 bytes. And, of those 3 bytes, 10 bits are reserved for the `hours`, which pretty much determines the overall range.

That said, 10 bits does allow values up to `1023`, so I guess, technically, without any changes to the storage size, the range could have been `-1023:59:59` to `1023:59:59`. Why they didn't do that and they chose `838` as the cutoff, I have no idea.

Comment: Looks like the Pascal 3byte float representation ... BTW: no place for leap-seconds?