# Converting date in to snowflake - (-838:59:59)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I do have several dates that needed to be converted in to snowflake.

please note the below dates. These needed to be converted in to dates
example 1 - (-838:59:59)
example 2 - (-558:41:34)

I dont know what type of date formats are these even. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I cannot recall ever seeing a date format that looks like that.

Comment: If you don't know what dates you want out of those numbers, how could we know?

Comment: @felipe hoffa read my post again. then you can know my requirement i dont know even the resulted output.  If you dont know how to convert these in to date values, then please stop messing around. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't transform (-838:59:59) into a date, because it's not a date.

It just happens to be the minimum time limit in MySQL, and it probably represents corrupted input data.

[Why is MySQL's maximum time limit 838:59:59?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259910/why-is-mysqls-maximum-time-limit-8385959)

Answer (score 1):

One of the other way you can get this done is via a function in snowflake. For reference you can refer to a similar solution in the below thread:

https://itqna.net/questions/5458/timediff-limited-838-59-59-how-solve